# Html2canvas + Angular2 : Rendering an element and appending the canvas to the body?

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I am trying to use html2canvas in my angular2 project, I would create an element and append the canvas to the body as described below:

```
let newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
let newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
newDiv.appendChild(newContent); 
html2canvas(newDiv).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

but I got the below error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'removeAttribute' of null TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'removeAttribute' of null

Any idea please to  fix this error ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you have to install types defintions and import it in your project :

```
npm install --save @types/html2canvas
```

Comment: already used   "@types/html2canvas": "^0.5.33" & "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",

Comment: for information, no error found when rendering  document.body, my question is how to create an element with "document.createElement" and render it